# How to monitor the hard disk usage of Nginx server blocks?

Tags: nginx

We run a small hosting company hosting mainly WordPress on a LEMP stack.

What is the best way to monitor the hard disk usage of the different server blocks (vhosts) created by Nginx? We do not wish to limit the amount of hard disk space of each website hosted on our servers at this stage, just monitor the usage so that we know how much disk space each site is taking up on the server.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Wait a minute, nginx doesn't create vhosts, you do!

Answer (score 0):

Nginx doesn't create vhosts, it just serves data from the location(s) you specify.

Use the command [ncdu](https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu) to manually monitor disk usage. Do you need some kind of automatic reporting? You may be able to script sending it to email.